# How can I divide a signed integer using only binary operators?

Tags: c, binary, division, signed-integer

I can only use ! ~ & ^ | + << >>

I am writing this in C.

I am trying to divide a number x by 2^n.
So i thought if I shift x >> n that would work, but it does not work with odd negative integers. It originally looked like this:

```
int dl18(int x, int n) {
   return (x >> n);
 }
```

but if x = -9 and n = 1 the output should be -4 but it is -5.
and if x = -9 and n = 0 the output is correct (-9).

Thanks in advance.

So I figured out doing this makes it work for everything unless n = 0 and x is a negative number:

```
return (~(x >> 31) & (x >> n)) | ((x >> 31) & ((x >> n) + 1));
```

Comment: FYI, the division operator `/` is binary too. "Binary" means it has two operands as opposed to "unary" and "ternary".

Comment: Just compensate for the round-down that `>>` has

Comment: I specified which binary operators i am allowed to use, and / is not one of them. Also, i dont think its so straight-forward as to round, because then if n = 0 the output will be wrong.

Comment: "does not work with odd negative integers." -->> Hmmm, first thing I'd try is to negate the number (with `~` and others), shift, and negate again - which certainly should work except for maybe corner cases. Then I would post looking for simplifications.

Comment: @chux Negating it will make it much more dependent on the implementation.

Comment: Can code use operators like `<` or `>` as part of the solution?

Comment: sadly, no @chux

Comment: Can code assume 2's compleiment?  Can code assume a 32-bit `int`?

Comment: yes, 2's complement and 32 bit int @chux

Comment: @EugeneSh.  How about `return (~(x >> 31) & (x >> n)) | ((x >> 31) & (~((1 + ~(x+0u)) >> n) + 1));`?  Suppose the final `unsigned` to `int` is ID or UB.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) representation of signed integers and [arithmetic shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift) behaviour of `>>` operator, the answer could be:

```
int dl18(int x, int n) {
    if (x < 0) {
        x += (1 << n) - 1;
    }
    return x >> n;
}
```

The addition is necessary, because `>>` rounds for negative numbers towards negative infinity. By adding `2^n - 1`, the result is always truncated towards zero, just like it happens for `/` operator.

Due to your requirements, assuming that `int` has `4` bytes (and to be extra pedantic `CHAR_BIT = 8`), the expression may be rewritten (obfuscated) as:

```
(x + ((x >> 31) & ((1 << n) + ~0))) >> n
```

The idea of `x >> 31` is to replicate MSB bit, so the mask becomes either all ones (i.e. `0xFFFFFFFF`), or all zeros, which is then used to either preserve or eliminate `((1 << n) - 1)` from addition. Parentheses around `&` are necessary, because addition has [higher precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) than bitwise AND.

This algorithm is also used by GCC compiler. For instance:

```
int dl18_4(int x) { return x / 4; }
```

translates with `-O1` into:

```
dl18_4:
        lea     eax, [rdi+3]    ; eax = rdi + 3
        test    edi, edi        ; set sign flag if edi < 0
        cmovns  eax, edi        ; eax = edi if SF = 0
        sar     eax, 2          ; eax = eax >> 2
        ret
```

Note that shifting by negative number invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), so it may be safer to declare second parameter as `unsigned int`.

Comment: ok, thanks! I cant use loops, so ill try and figure out how to do this without them.

Comment: oh ok this makes sense! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Bailey: I made a typo with operator precedence, it's fixed. Also, I noticed that `-` operator is apparently not allowed, so `- 1` is now replaced with `+ ~0`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that avoids bit-shifting negative values. It does assume twos-complement representation, but it does not use the unary negative operator.

A bitmask is used to set `neg` to a non-zero value if `x` is negative, or to zero if `x` is non-negative. Here a trick suggested by [@Grzegorz Szpetkowski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/586873/grzegorz-szpetkowski) is used to avoid subtraction by 1: adding `~0` instead. If `x` is negative, the value of `x` is changed to the magnitude of `x`. To avoid using the unary negative here, using a trick suggested by [@chux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41968998/how-can-i-divide-a-signed-integer-using-only-binary-operators/41970767?noredirect=1#comment71120173_41970767), we take advantage of the fact that for a negative value in twos-complement, the corresponding positive value is equal to the bitwise negation of the negative representation plus 1.

This magnitude of `x` can be bit-shifted without encountering implementation-dependent behavior. After performing the division, the result is converted back to a negative value if the original value was negative, by performing the same transformation as before.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int divide_2n(int x, unsigned n);

int main(void)
{
    printf("-7 / 4 = %d\n", divide_2n(-7, 2));
    printf("27 / 8 = %d\n", divide_2n(27, 3));
    printf("-27 / 8 = %d\n", divide_2n(-27, 3));
    printf("-9 / 2 = %d\n", divide_2n(-9, 1));
    printf("-9 / 1 = %d\n", divide_2n(-9, 0));

    return 0;
}

int divide_2n(int x, unsigned n)
{
    unsigned n_bits = CHAR_BIT * sizeof(int);
    unsigned neg = x & (1U << (n_bits + ~0));

    if (neg) {
        x = ~(unsigned)x + 1;
    }

    x = (unsigned)x >> n;

    if (neg) {
        x = ~x + 1;
    }

    return x;
}

-7 / 4 = -1
27 / 8 = 3
-27 / 8 = -3
-9 / 2 = -4
-9 / 1 = -9
```

Comment: Code uses `-` in `(1UL << n_bits) - (unsigned)(x)`.  I do not see `-` in "can only use ! ~ & ^ | + << >>"

Comment: Curious, why `L` in `1UL`.  `unsigned long` may not be any wider than `unsigned`.  Perhaps `(1UL << n_bits) - (unsigned)(x)` --> `~(unsigned)(x) + 1;`?  As in my [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41968998/how-can-i-divide-a-signed-integer-using-only-binary-operators#comment71117864_41968998)

Comment: @chux-- I have updated my answer. It seems to me that the cast to `unsigned` is not necessary at all. In other words, `~(unsigned)(x) + 1` --> `~x + 1`. Am I missing something here?

Comment: `~(unsigned)(some_int) + 1` in itself will not cause UB for all values of `some_int`.  `~some_int` is UB on select machines, maybe in a computer graveyard.  `~` on non-2's complement does not lend itself to arithmetic negation.   IAC, it is all a learning exercise.  "If the implementation does not support negative zeros, the behavior of the &, |, ^, ~, <<, and >> operators with operands that would produce such a value is undeﬁned. " C11 §6.2.6.2 4

Comment: @chux-- Appreciate the informative comments. Final question: I changed my code to cast `x` before the first transformation to a positive magnitude, but if negative zero representations are the only issue, could we not instead test for zero before applying `~`, and proceed accordingly?

Comment: `INT_MIN` is an issue.  Consider `x = ~(unsigned)(INT_MIN) + 1;`.  Suggest using well behaved `unsigned` for the `>>` shift rather than `int x` with its ID behavior.

Comment: @chux-- you are suggesting `x >>= n` --> `x = (unsigned)x >> n`? When I changed this the code worked for `x = INT_MIN`; without the cast the sign was lost on my machine. Will have to think about this some more. Good tip.